# VBA loop won't stop/doesn't find the "\EndofDoc" marker

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a vba macro to search a word document line by line and trying to find certain names in the document.  The looping works fine except for when it gets to the end of the document, it just continues from the top and starts over.  Here is the code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim i As Integer, Rng As Range
 With ActiveDocument.Range
   With .Find
     .ClearFormatting
     .Replacement.ClearFormatting
     .Text = "?"
     .Replacement.Text = ""
     .Forward = True
     .Wrap = wdFindStop
     .Format = False
     .MatchWildcards = True
     .Execute
   End With
   Do While .Find.found
     i = i + 1
     Set Rng = .Duplicate
     Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\line")
     MsgBox "Line " & i & vbTab & Rng.Text
     If Rng.Bookmarks.Exists("\EndOfDoc") Then Exit Do
     .start = Rng.End
     .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
     .Find.Execute
   Loop
 End With
 Set Rng = Nothing
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I have also tried this piece of code:

```
Dim appWD As Word.Application
 Dim docWD As Word.Document
 Dim rngWD As Word.Range
 Dim strDoc As String
 Dim intVal As Integer
 Dim strLine As String
 Dim bolEOF As Boolean

bolEOF = False

' Set strDoc here to include the full
 ' file path and file name

On Error Resume Next
 Set appWD = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 End If
 Err.Clear
 On Error GoTo 0

strDoc = "c:\KenGraves\Project2\output\master.doc"
Set docWD = appWD.Documents.Open(strDoc)
 appWD.Visible = True

docWD.Characters(1).Select

Do
 appWD.Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
 strLine = appWD.Selection.Text
 Debug.Print strLine
 intVal = LineContainsDescendant(strLine)
 If intVal = 1 Then
    MsgBox strLine
 End If
 appWD.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

If appWD.Selection.Bookmarks.Exists("\EndOfDoc") Then bolEOF = True
 Loop Until bolEOF = True
```

Neither seem to recognize the bookmark ("\EndOfDoc").  It doesn't matter which one gets working.  Is it possible that my document does not contain this bookmark?

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly elegant, but this change to one line of your first procedure seems to stop it at the appropriate time.  I believe you actually have to insert bookmarks into your document if you want to reference them.  They aren't automatically generated.

```
     If i >= ActiveDocument.BuiltInProperties("NUMBER OF LINES") Then Exit Do
```

Cheers, LC

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a corrupted document, all Word documents should have the `\EndOfDoc` bookmark.  You can check using simply `ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Exists`.  If it doesn't then you'll need to supply more details on the version of Word and if possible supply a sample document via Dropbox or the like.

I'm not sure why you're looping to the start of the Word document, when I run the code it works fine.  However, if I put a footnote at the end of the document it runs into an endless loop, depending on your documents you may run into additional situations like this where your code fails to handle the document setup.

I would suggest modifying slightly how you check for the end of the document to make your code a bit more robust.  I'd still use the bookmark "\EndOfDoc", however I'd check the limits of the range against your current search range.

So at the top of your code declare a range variable and set it to range of the end of the document eg:

```
Dim rEnd As Range
Set rEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range
```

and then in your loop, instead of this line:

```
If Rng.Bookmarks.Exists("\EndOfDoc") Then Exit Do
```

use this line:

```
If Rng.End >= rEnd.End Then Exit Do
```